# How to integrate monkeyrunner integration testing with emma coverage testing?

Tags: android, testing, integration-testing, monkeyrunner, emma

I have created an android app and I'd like to analyze the code coverage of integration tests.  Assuming the activities as units, I have tested the interaction between some activities (with `monkeyrunner`) so as to validate some scenarios of my app's use cases.

- Is it possible to evaluate my integration tests' code coverage through tools like `Emma`?
- If so, is it possible to run `monkeyrunner` scripts while `Emma` computes the coverage?

I have just found tutorials that show how computes `Emma` code coverage for Android Unit Test...

Answer (score 0):

[Obtaining code coverage of a running Android application](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2011/11/obtaining-code-coverage-of-running.html) is probably what you are looking for.

Also, for creating your tests I would recommend giving [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) a try as a `monkeyrunner` drop-in replacement, which allows automatic generation of tests just recording your actions on the screen (try `culebra -UG`).

Comment: Hi, you do not use monkeyrunner in the guide...unfortunately I MUST use it to test my app.